# Summary pivot table from matrix data

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, excel-pivot

I have an excel file that contains a table formatted in this way (the example here below is just notional):

**Table 1**

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | Option 12 | Option 33 |
| Group B | Option 11 | Option 15 |
| Group B | Option 12 | Option 13 |
| Group B | Option 1 | Option 10 |
| Group A | Option 1 | Option 13 |
| Group B | Option 12 | Option 15 |

Out of this table, I would like to create a Pivot table that provides the following summary (basically shows the count for each option, grouped by the Group)

**Table 2**

| - | Option 1 | Option 10 | Option 11 | Option 12 | Option 13 | Option 15 | Option 33 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Group B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

In order to obtain this result, I found that I need  to "unroll" **Table 1** like this (selecting **Table 1** does not produce the expected results in **Table 2**):

**Table 3**

| Column A repeated twice | Column B/C merged |
| --- | --- |
| Group A | Option 12 |
| Group B | Option 11 |
| Group B | Option 12 |
| Group B | Option 1 |
| Group A | Option 1 |
| Group B | Option 12 |
| Group A | Option 33 |
| Group B | Option 15 |
| Group B | Option 13 |
| Group B | Option 10 |
| Group A | Option 13 |
| Group B | Option 15 |

Does anyone know if is it possible to get **Table 2** results using **Table 1** data, instead of **Table 3** ?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that Table 2 is not properly visualized; I tried to modify it, but  I was not allowed to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire transformation can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table28"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column A", type text}, {"Column B", type text}, {"Column C", type text}}),

//Unpivot columns except for the first
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column A"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//Remove Attribute column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),

//Make a list of the Options which will be used as column headers in the Pivoted table
//This will be sorted alphabetically, but could be sorted alphanumerically if necessary
    colHdrs = List.Sort(List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Value])),

//Group by "Group" in Column A
//Then aggregate by Pivoting each sub group
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Column A"}, {
        {"Pivot", each Table.Pivot(_, colHdrs, "Value","Value", List.Count)}}),

//Expand the aggregated group pivots
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Pivot", colHdrs),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Pivot", List.Transform(colHdrs, each {_, Int64.Type}))
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Power Query to unpivot your data, then create the new pivot table.

With your data selected, go to Data > Get & Transform Data > From Table / Range. Excel will format it as a table and open the Power Query editor.

In the Power Query editor, right click Column A > Unpivot other columns. Right click the "Attribute" column > Remove. Then click Close & Load. That will give you the green table in Excel.

From the new table in Excel, insert a pivot table. The Value field should go in Columns and Values, and the Column A field should go in Rows.

[image]